# oauth2 cli for vuejs (implicit flow)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, vue.js, openid, openid-connect

I've been searching for an oauth2 client which supports implicit flow. It will be used in a VueJS app (+ webpack) so it has to run in the browser with javascript.

I'm working around this since 2 weeks ago, so I don't fully understand what it means, therefore any help is grateful.

I used https://github.com/jasonkuhrt/oauth2-implicit but it doesn't return the token, so it's not valid.

At the moment, I'm trying with https://github.com/saitolabs/vuejs-oidc-client but the documentation is not clear enough so I can't make it work.

**Edit**:
I'm looking for something like this https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client but for vuejs or javascript. (OpenID Connect Implicit Flow) I've been trying with this one and it works.

Any idea? Do you know how can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate ?

Comment: Can I use my own method instead the common providers like fb, tw, gh, etc?

Comment: I guess you can configure your own provider, the majors are just given examples https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate/blob/master/src/options.js#L53

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, you may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646181/need-assistance-in-integrating-oauth-in-vuejs-app/63648105#63648105